# Expressing a circuit in the form of block diagram

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, layout

I am doing an electronics project for 12th grade in electronics.This project is about water level controller.I have component list along with the description and I have soldered the circuit as told.I also have a simple circuit diagram.But after that i am not getting how to express the functioning of the circuit in terms of a block diagram.So it would be of great help if u explain me the description and block diagram.

Thank you.[image: description]
[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Just build it.. see what happens.. the description seems pretty good to me, what EXACTLY is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Electronics SE!  Homework questions are generally off-topic here. Try working through things on your own first.  If you still have problems, CLEAR and FOCUSED questions will get a much better response from the community.

Comment: Ditto the previous comments.  First try your best to understand the digital part of this circuit.  The way the front end works assumes that the resistance of the water will be less than 100k ohm.  (I'm not sure if this is true.. but you could always check and add some salt to the water to make it more conductive.)

Comment: The photos of the description and schematic are pretty bad (no contrast). Can *you* read them?  Once you get past that, the description is rather thorough. I don't think any of us here are going to want to go through it sentence by sentence and explain it to you. If you have questions, I suggest you ask your instructor.

Comment: hey KyranF,i hav built it and its working but when it comes to  block diagram i am stuck over there and its like I am supposed to write about each block in the block diagram.Also i am not getting any proper guidance for it.But i have managed to draw the pcb layout. Also I have made a model to present it...its like installed in the vicinity of a house to control water level.Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: @AdamHead:Sorry for not being able to ask the question in the right way.I have tried my best to understand the circuit.I have soldered the circuit n its working but was unable to express it on paper in the form of block diagram.Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This circuit is based on the fluid's conductivity (which I would say is quite dubious).

N3,N5,N7 are just low-pass buffers. When water does not touch the submerged electrodes, pull-up resistors R1,R2,R3 (I would increase them to 1M) will propagate 12 V to the buffers' inputs. When the electrodes come in contact with the water, the inputs will be shorted to ground.

N4 and N8 are inverters.

N1 and N2 form an SR latch.

T1 and T2 are the output power stage, the transistor is doubled to increase current gain.

**Update:** block diagram can be something like this:

\$\fbox{Water level} \longrightarrow \fbox{Sensing pads} \longrightarrow\fbox{Signal conditioning} \longrightarrow\fbox{Control logic} \longrightarrow\fbox{Power stage} \longrightarrow\fbox{Water pump} \longrightarrow (back\ to\ start)\$

Comment: Hello venny i have soldered the circuit as told but i am facing problem while expressing the circuit in terms of block diagram.I am doing it for first time and am not getting it.Please help

Comment: thank u for the help:)Had no idea about block diagram.Please i want to confirm from u about each of those blocks.I will keep it basic as i am really new to it.I might go wrong but i will try my best.1)Water level:Starting from the tanks,it indicates the water level in each tank2)Sensing pads:these are the wires(mostly)which are inserted in the tanks to indicate water level.3)Signal conditioning:these are the ICs which carry out all the processing functions 4)Control logic:these include the gates which carry out logical functions 5)Power: 6)water pump: which pumps out water from the tank

Comment: @user1396721 Signal conditioning is N3,N5,N7,R1,R2,R3,C1,C2,C3 and converts resistance between sensor pads to logic signals. Control logic is N1,N2,N4,N6,N8 (yes, they carry out processing functions). Power stage is R4,T1,T2,LED,R5,RL1,D1 and is used to switch current into the water pump.